# How can I best repair separated wood floor boards?

Tags: wood, flooring

There are two 20 foot long wall to wall separations that have occurred in our oak floor over a period of several years. The boards are 2" wide and the picture is an accurate representation of the damage over the entire 20 feet. It looks as though a previous owner had filled them in with some kind of putty that is breaking up.  The floor is built over a crawlspace without humidity control. The rest of the floor looks great. Any recommendations on a stopgap solution (sorry about the pun)?

[image]

Comment: It’s hard to tell is that an old filler or dirt? It makes a difference, if the separation was filled originally, about your only option is to clean it out and re fill. If dirt and shrinkage at the end of a cold dry spell cleaning and oiling the wood can help, there are other possibilities but they depend on the structure, how the floor was laid. I know you mentioned filler and crawl space , how old is the floor? How old is the home. I have a 1930 home with a crawl space and after a little work the boards are tight in the 1 room that they were loose.

Comment: I am getting back to this project and am finding that there are a lot of wood filler products out there but none that advertise using on wood floors.  Minwax advises against using their filler on floors.  Any suggestions?  The home is about 17 years old.